# Need help differentiating between mocks and test drivers

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, integration-testing

I'm confused to say the least. I might be getting Mocks wrong, Test Drivers wrong or maybe both.

My understanding of Mocks is that it's a way of imitating units, to avoid depending on specific parts of your system when testing.

My understanding of Test Drivers is that it's specifically used for Bottom-up integration testing, to imitate High Level Modules, which haven't been implemented yet.

To me that makes Test Drivers sound like a type of Mock, but are Mocks specifically a unit testing thing?

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it in the following way:

**Mock:**

You have standard layered application, e.g. Controller->Service->Repository. You want to unit test it. So you are using mocks and injecting Repository Mock into Service, so you can isolate Service testing.

**Test Driver:**

You have same application, Controller->Service->Repository. You did all unit tests and now you want to test Repository Level. It doesn't make much sense to use Mocks during Repository testing because they will not show if your sql queries are correct. So it's time for integration tests. Also you don't want to test entire system ( which may consist of 100 services ), you want to isolate your application, so you are spinning up, let's say, docker container with database ( or embedded database, like h2) and running your queries on this database for testing only.

Same example is applicable for other services clients, e.g. you want to get something by HTTP, and instead of calling real service, you spin up MOCK SERVER, e.g. wiremock.

> Drivers are the modules that act as temporary replacement for a calling module and give the same output as that of the actual product.
>
> Drivers are also used when the software needs to interact with an external system and are usually complex than stubs.

To recap:

Mocks are small in memory objects, that have very simple configuration and they used during unit testing for isolation of classes.

Test drivers are more complicated, they are used during integration testing to replace components into your infrastructure for isolation of entire application.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me. Glad to hear that i wasn't totally off in my initial thoughts. Thanks for elaborating.